# Is there a way to change the position of the ball to the centre when scored?

Tags: pygame, pong

```
  if fireBall.rect.x>=690:
      score_1+=1
      fireBall.ballspeed[0] = -fireBall.ballspeed[0]
  if fireBall.rect.x<=0:
      score_2+=1
      fireBall.ballspeed[0] = -fireBall.ballspeed[0]
  if fireBall.rect.y>490:
      fireBall.ballspeed[1] = -fireBall.ballspeed[1]
  if fireBall.rect.y<0:
      fireBall.ballspeed[1] = -fireBall.ballspeed[1]
```

I am making a ping pong game, I wanted the ball to restart at the centre when the player scores, but my code allows the ball to carry on moving even after they have scored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the the center of the window with `pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect().center`. e.g.:

```py
if fireBall.rect.x>=690:
    score_1+=1
    fireBall.ballspeed[0] = -fireBall.ballspeed[0]
    fireBall.rect.center = pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect().center
  
if fireBall.rect.x<=0:
    score_2+=1
    fireBall.ballspeed[0] = -fireBall.ballspeed[0]
    fireBall.rect.center = pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect().center
```